# Directory named "linux-4.13.10" containing content of 13 GB in Downloads?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

Recently, was trying to free up some space, and I found a directory named "linux-4.13.10" having Size of 13 GB, present in my Downloads.
I couldn't understand why it was there. I updated Ubuntu sometimes ago, and also updated the kernel recently.
Can I delete it, and free up some space or it could mess up the OS.

> uname -a

> Linux ...... 4.15.0-128-generic #131-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 06:57:35 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
(base) imran@imran:~/Downloads/linux-4.13.10$ ls -lah
total 1.1G
drwxrwxr-x  25 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x  21 imran imran  16K Dec 24 23:19 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Nov  5  2017 .10137.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Nov  4  2017 .10362.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Nov  5  2017 .11603.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Nov  5  2017 .14317.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Nov  5  2017 .14395.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Oct 28  2017 .15038.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Nov  5  2017 .15402.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Oct 28  2017 .15916.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Nov  5  2017 .18544.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   22 Oct 28  2017 .24605.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3105.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3331.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3435.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3462.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3541.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3571.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3599.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3636.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  6  2017 .3645.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3657.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3674.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3676.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3689.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3715.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3719.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3735.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3799.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3803.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3984.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .3989.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4027.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4059.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4080.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4098.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4122.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4131.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4145.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4160.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  6  2017 .4174.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4202.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4203.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4216.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4235.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4237.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4247.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4252.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4266.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4276.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4292.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4403.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4436.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  4  2017 .4496.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4541.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4562.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4564.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4685.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .4710.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5042.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5161.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5173.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5210.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5217.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5222.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5274.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5323.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5411.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5477.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5706.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5763.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  4  2017 .5850.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .5982.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .6041.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .6381.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .6428.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .6703.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .7436.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .7901.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .7975.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .8164.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .8375.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .8557.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .9125.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  6  2017 .9366.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   21 Nov  5  2017 .9868.d
drwxrwxr-x  33 imran imran 4.0K Oct 28  2017 arch
drwxrwxr-x   3 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 block
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 524K Nov  6  2017 built-in.o
drwxrwxr-x   2 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 certs
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   59 Oct 27  2017 .cocciconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 imran imran 201K Nov  4  2017 config
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran  88K Nov  6  2017 .config
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran  88K Nov  6  2017 .config.old
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran  19K Oct 27  2017 COPYING
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran  97K Oct 27  2017 CREDITS
drwxrwxr-x   4 imran imran  28K Nov  6  2017 crypto
drwxrwxr-x 121 imran imran  12K Oct 27  2017 Documentation
drwxrwxr-x 132 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 drivers
drwxrwxr-x  36 imran imran 4.0K Nov  4  2017 firmware
drwxrwxr-x  74 imran imran  12K Nov  6  2017 fs
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   31 Oct 27  2017 .get_maintainer.ignore
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   30 Oct 27  2017 .gitattributes
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 1.3K Oct 27  2017 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  30 imran imran 4.0K Oct 28  2017 include
drwxrwxr-x   2 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 init
drwxrwxr-x   2 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 ipc
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 2.3K Oct 27  2017 Kbuild
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran  252 Oct 27  2017 Kconfig
drwxrwxr-x  17 imran imran  12K Nov  6  2017 kernel
drwxrwxr-x  12 imran imran  28K Nov  6  2017 lib
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 8.2K Oct 27  2017 .mailmap
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 411K Oct 27  2017 MAINTAINERS
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran  59K Oct 27  2017 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran  485 Nov  6  2017 .missing-syscalls.d
drwxrwxr-x   3 imran imran  12K Nov  6  2017 mm
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 4.8K Nov  6  2017 modules.builtin
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 2.1K Nov  6  2017 modules.order
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 466K Nov  6  2017 Module.symvers
drwxrwxr-x  69 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 net
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran  722 Oct 27  2017 README
drwxrwxr-x  27 imran imran 4.0K Oct 27  2017 samples
drwxrwxr-x  14 imran imran 4.0K Oct 28  2017 scripts
drwxrwxr-x  10 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 security
drwxrwxr-x  24 imran imran 4.0K Nov  5  2017 sound
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 2.7M Nov  6  2017 System.map
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 1.1M Nov  6  2017 .tmp_kallsyms1.o
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 6.2M Nov  6  2017 .tmp_kallsyms1.S
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 1.1M Nov  6  2017 .tmp_kallsyms2.o
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 6.2M Nov  6  2017 .tmp_kallsyms2.S
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 2.7M Nov  6  2017 .tmp_System.map
drwxrwxr-x   2 imran imran 140K Nov  6  2017 .tmp_versions
-rwxrwxr-x   1 imran imran 258M Nov  6  2017 .tmp_vmlinux1
-rwxrwxr-x   1 imran imran 260M Nov  6  2017 .tmp_vmlinux2
drwxrwxr-x  31 imran imran 4.0K Oct 27  2017 tools
drwxrwxr-x   2 imran imran 4.0K Nov  6  2017 usr
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran    3 Nov  6  2017 .version
drwxrwxr-x   4 imran imran 4.0K Oct 28  2017 virt
-rwxrwxr-x   1 imran imran 260M Nov  6  2017 vmlinux
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran   99 Nov  6  2017 .vmlinux.cmd
lrwxrwxrwx   1 imran imran   62 Nov  6  2017 vmlinux-gdb.py -> /home/imran/Downloads/linux-4.13.10/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
-rw-rw-r--   1 imran imran 302M Nov  6  2017 vmlinux.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in your downloads folder I would say it is safe to delete it.

Comment: Yeah, old kernel `source code` isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a perfectly ordinary kernel source tree although given the total size I think it's possible you used `git` to pull in a great deal more than you actually needed.

It should be safe to remove, regardless.

... Also, the current (as of December 2020) 4.x kernel is 4.19, and 5.10 came out not too long ago; if you're still on 4.15 another update may be in order.

Comment: It's a kernel source tree *that has been built*, and the build process will have generated a lot of object files, auto-generated pieces of code and other temporary files that remain after the build process is complete. If it's necessary to keep the source tree for some reason, `cd`ing into the root of the source tree and running `make clean` would clean up most of this without sacrificing the ability to still compile third-party modules for the kernel built from this configured kernel source.